# java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path path/path/JPEG_5e3bbe8ed6c75_24741_.jpg

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

This is not working on Some Devices. 
In Samsung Device they not allow to download file using Download manager.
I have already define permission in the manifest and also get RunTime Permission.

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
request.setTitle("");
request.setDescription("");
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
request.setMimeType("*/*");
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Did you check all your permissions ? Write exteranal storage, read external storage etc..

Comment: yes, I did check that. not able to download in some devices.this and throws this exception.

Comment: can you post your path that you want to download?

Comment: This is my path where i want to download image :
java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path /storage/emulated/0/GoldalEngineering/JPEG_5e3bbe8ed6c75_24741_.jpg

Comment: if you download this path from another devices, if your problem is only about Samsung devices, I am not sure about it. At the moment, DownloadManager request accepts only paths on the "standard" external storage, as retrieved by Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(yourDirOfChoice) or Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); otherwise, it throws this exception.

Comment: Same issue I am getting in Emulator with Android Version Q[10].

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(
            context.applicationContext,
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
            ""
        )
```

Comment: Please remove "request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));"

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem with **runtime permission** if you are running the download manager on Marshamellow+, So you should request runtime permission, it's not adequate to add permission in Manifest file.
Check [runtime permission from official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) it would guide you to solve the problem.

Note: we should request storage permission as it considered as dangerous permission. on the other hand, we don't have to request Internet permission because it's a normal one. I hope this suffices.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I did ask Run Time Permission before downloading File in Application.
It is working Fine below Android Q even this issue fetch in Emulator also.

Comment: it's the setDestinationUri, remove it.